# How to get unique values from LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a `DropDownList` which gets its data from this query:

```
    using (ProjectEntities myEntities = new ProjectEntities ())
                {
                    var q = (from c in myEntities.Customers orderby c.Name select c.Name);
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = q.ToList();
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

How to get just the unique names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add **[`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx)**

```
 var q = (from c in myEntities.Customers orderby c.Name select c.Name);
 DropDownList1.DataSource = q.ToList().Distinct();
```

or on the query itself,

```
 var q = (from c in myEntities.Customers orderby c.Name select c.Name).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Distinct()` method on the result you get from your current linq expression.

```
var q = (from c in myEntities.Customers orderby c.Name select c.Name).Distinct();
```

or

```
var q = myEntities.Customers.OrderBy(s=>s.Name).Select(f=>f.Name).Distinct();
```